# Integration with trigonometric functions

Tags: integration

I had a bad time trying to underestand how to make integration when them involve trigonometric functions.

Here is an example,

$$\int \frac{\sin x }{\cos^2 x } \ dx$$

Can you explain step-by-step solution for this?  Fell free to expose any example that you consider illustrative.

Thanks!

Comment: Substitution $u = \cos x$ would work here.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) For any differentiable function $\,f(x)\;$ and for all $\,-1\ne n\in\Bbb R\;$:

$$\int f'(x)f(x)^ndx=\frac{f(x)^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$

2) We have that

$$(\cos x)'=-\sin x$$

(3) Also

$$\frac1{\cos^2x}=\cos^{-2}x$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}=\sec x\tan x$.

Do you remember by differentiate which trigonometric function will you obtain this?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int \frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}\, dx = \int \frac{-1}{\cos^2 x}\Big( -\sin x \, dx \Big).
$$
The reason for looking at it this way is that $-\sin x$ is the derivative of $\cos x$, so that if $u=\cos x$ then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=-\sin x$, so $du = -\sin x\,dx$.  Thus we have
$$
\int \frac{-1}{u^2}\, du.
$$
Then once you've found that
$$
\int \frac{-1}{u^2}\, du = \frac 1u+C,
$$
you can change $u$ back to $\cos x$.  Then you might want to recall that $\dfrac{1}{\cos x}=\sec x$.